# Sending attachment ID Image in a generic template, facebook messenger platform

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger-bot

we are working with a messenger chatbot where we use generic templates to show clients some of the productos that are availablle and a couple of buttons to do some actions over the products selected, i am trying to send a attachment id instead of an image URL to be able to see the image in the generic template, i'm trying to believe that this is not posible but if someone somewhere has achieved this and share the info with me, it would be great.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use attachment id in generic template. But if you've no option to host the images, you can use the product template which fetches product from your page shop. Note that you can send only one product at a time, not a carousal. Also, you can try the media template.